# JQuery drop originalevent.target is the element being dragged - why?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, droppable

We have converted our app to using JQuery UI for drag and drop.  (I was not involved in that, nor in the original code.  I'm just trying to fix this issue.)  We are dragging new "columns" into a table.  We have the drop-target set as the whole table, not the individual rows/cells.  Until I started making changes to remove one of our drop targets, the event.originalEvent.target has always given us the cell in the table that the user dropped on.  We use information about that cell to determine where the user actually wants to drop the new column.

As I said above, the issue started when I tried to remove one of our drop targets.  Whenever I get rid of it (and all references to it, that show it and hide it during the drag/drop action), then in my Drop function, the event.originalEvent.target element (of the mouseup event) is no longer the column in the table where the user let go of the mouse.  Instead it is the element being dragged around.

I don't know why the presence or absence of that extra drop target would change what element the mouse-up event sees as its target.  It seems to be related to the visibility of this item, that it gets shown and hidden dynamically.  If I change any of these things, I get the dragged item instead of what it's being dragged over.  The only time I get what's under the dragged item is if this "extra" drop target exists, is initially hidden, gets shown during the drag and then gets hidden again on drop.

Do you know how I can either (a) get the drop-event to give me what's UNDER the dragged item, or (b) get the proper coordinates of the mouse-up relative to the actual drop target (the table), in a way that I can use to find the item relative to the table?  Or do I really have to make all the cells of the table into drop-targets?  I really just want to remove this one div from my page.

Comment: Could you add some code to show what you have tried so far?  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: I found a solution to my issue.  I'm only dragging one item at a time.  If I hide the dragged element, then I can query what's under the clientX/clientY and find the table cell.  I was also able to build a test sample at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfhsknro/2/)